# How can I use a "for each" clause in a patent claim?

Tags: claims, claim-construction

Consider the claim:

```
A method comprising:
  accessing a line, the line comprising a plurality of points;
  for each point on the line:
    generating an X.
```

Do I now have a plurality of X's?  Do I need to marshal them somehow, like so?

```
A method comprising:
  accessing a line, the line comprising a plurality of points;
  for each point on the line:
    generating an X;
  aggregating the X's into a plurality of X's.
```

What about "each"?  ClaimMaster definitely does not like those.

```
A method comprising:
  accessing a line, the line comprising a plurality of points;
  for each point on the line:
    generating an X;
  for each generated X, do Y;
  do Z for the X's generated for each point on the line.
```

What is the best way to approach this kind of clause?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a claim as narrow as a particular loop, there is a much simpler way to do it than to port your loop to claimese: simply recite "step for processing points" and include a flowchart along with an adequate supporting description in the specification (you must have more than one "step for" in the claim to avoid the technical pitfall of single means).

Normally, you will want a broader claim, which is where things get tricky. I would avoid thinking in terms of loops.

Answer (score 2):

“each” is very dangerous. If you require each X to have a Y, you are saying *every* X needs to have a Y in order to infringe. A product, method etc. with an extraneous X that is free of a corresponding Y will not infringe.

In your case “for at least some points on the line”. Or “at least two points” if that is needed.